# Почему выходит ошибка при использвании .style

Tags: javascript

Нужно изменить CSS свойство объекта, не удаляя предыдущие значения.
Написал функцию,

```
function DealCardKanban() { 
    'use strict';
    let CardKanban = document.getElementsByClassName('crm-kanban-item'); 
    CardKanban = Array.from(CardKanban);   
    CardKanban.forEach(StyleSet => {
        StyleSet.style.padding('8px 7px 7px 12px')
    });
};
DealCardKanban();
```

При попытке запуска в отладчике Chrome, выдает ошибку:
**Uncaught TypeError: StyleSet.style.padding is not a function**
С чем это связано?

Comment: А с чего вы взяли, что изменяется через функцию?

Comment: Может быть потому что padding - свойство, а не функция и ему нельзя передавать значение в скобках, а нужно присваивать? )) Не проверяя весь код на работоспособность, писать следует всё-равно так: `StyleSet.style.padding = '8px 7px 7px 12px'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасибо @Quazimorda за ответ

> padding - свойство, а не функция и ему нельзя передавать значение в
> скобках, а нужно присваивать